# Check if there is a letter in a list

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, filtering

Writing:

```
dictionary = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
vector = {a b/c, ef, d a^b, f};
For[
  i = 1, 
  i <= Length[dictionary], 
  i++,
  Quiet @ If[
    IntegerQ[Norm[D[vector, ToExpression[dictionary[[i]]]]]^0],
    Print[1],
    Print[0]
  ]
]
```

I get:

```
1
1
1
1
0
```

that is what is desired, that is to verify which letters of `dictionary` are present or not in `vector`.

This is definitely a horrible, inefficient method, etc. Could you recommend me a better method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you don't have to care about `a` and friends having values:

```
Boole @ Not @ FreeQ[vector, #] & /@ Symbol /@ dictionary
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}

in case where you care about e.g. `a=1`:

```
dictionary = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
a = b = c = 1;
vector = Hold[{a b/c, ef, d a^b, f}];


Boole @ Not @ FreeQ[vector, #] & /@ (
  ToExpression[#, StandardForm, HoldPattern] & /@ dictionary
)
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}

Answer (score 6):

```
Boole @ Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[vector, Symbol @ #] & /@ dictionary
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}

```
a = b = c = 1;
vector
```

> {1, ef, d, f}

```
Boole @ Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ[vector, Symbol @ #] & /@ dictionary
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}

Comment: Is ``Internal`LiterallyOccurringQ`` required here?  Isn't `Not[FreeQ[]]` good enough?

Comment: @QuantumDot, here, right. Not sure if they are the same in general.